# changing character code with js and show the new character instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keyboard-events

I want to write a code that if a user press a key, It changes the keyCode or charCode of the User event and trigger the event with a new charcode,

I wrote [this code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mosijava/0fv1cgd9/3/) but this code doesn't work because of too much recursion.

```js
function convert(e, elem) {
    function getKey(event) {
        if (event.which == null) {
            return event.keyCode // IE
        } else if (event.which != 0 && event.charCode != 0) {
            return event.which // the rest
        } else {
            return null // special key
        }
    }
    var key = getKey(e);

    key++;

    return key;
}

$(".myInput").keypress(function (e) {
    var returnedKey = convert(e, this);
    e.which = e.keyCode = returnedKey;
    $(this).trigger(e);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="myInput" />
```

any Idea that help my code work would be appreciated.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Side note: Where do you see _recursion_ there?

Comment: @hindmost triggering a keypress event inside a keypress function. But I don't know how to change the key only once.

Comment: @Mosijava Keyboard event properties are all READ-only. You cannot capture one keyCode and change it to another. Ref [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the recursion issue, you need to add a stopping condition, for example:

```
$(".myInput").keypress(function (e) {
  var returnedKey = convert(e, this);
   e.which = e.keyCode = returnedKey;
if(!e.isSecondTrigger){
    e.isSecondTrigger = true;
    $(this).trigger(e);
}});
```

This way, you only change the value once. However, as was stated by LShetty in the comments section, the event values are read only - you can't change the value of the button that was already pressed and in that way change the input text. In order to do this, you need to manually change the value of the input text after each user action (i.e. hold the value of the input text at each key press, modify it when the user presses a key, and then overwrite the input field value with the output).